# Assign multiple values to one string declared

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm looking for way around getting multiple values set to one variable declared as String. Following codes might give you a glimpse of what I'm looking for

```
Dim Name as string
Name = value1 or value2 or value3
If range("A1"). Value = Name then
    Activecell.entirecolumn.delete
End If
```

Comment: Can't you use array ?

Comment: You can, for example, add a `,` between your var then use a loop to check if the word between the `,` is the work you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim Name As String
    Dim value1 As String, value2 As String, value3 As String

    Name = value1 & "," & value2 & "," & value3

    If InStr(Name, Range("A1")) <> 0 Then
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
```

The program loop through A1 to see if one of the value match. If it does, Instr will return the position in Name where they match. So, simply tells your program that is Instr isn't equal to 0 to delete what you want

Comment: Mark it to say this helped and solved your problem, it will help ppl if they envounter the same problem

Comment: Question : Do I really have to mention limit like Name(3), can't I just say Name() and it will let me add as long as I want?

Comment: Of course you can, but if you can know how many obj there will be then put it. Or you can use `Dim Name(1 to 150)` to say there can be 1 to 150 object. Or just `Name()`

Comment: If you are sure `Name` will always have string, you can declare it as `Dim Name() as string`

Comment: Thanks, I think I'd just go with Name()   so that I don't have to count them and just add a value whenever required..

Comment: And yes, Its a string value

Comment: @Mohdakhtar ok perfect, have a nice day, and i'm glad i've helped you

Comment: I still need you. Its giving me compile error for sname.length

Comment: Hey@Hearner its giving compile error for `Name.Length`

It says "Invalid Qualifier"

Comment: I'll edit my answer and I've tested it and it perfectly works